# Eclipse project with many small files on network share - way too slow

Tags: eclipse, performance, file, networking

I run Eclipse (Win64, Indigo) to build a project containing many files (approx. 12000 files, all the files together account for 70 MiB).

Eclipse runs on a local machine, but the project and it's sources are located on a Samba share.

Whenever I start Eclipse and/or switch to the workspace with that project, Eclipse gets terribly slow. Refreshing the workspace takes up to 20 minutes (or sometimes hangs even longer). Building the project takes 40 minutes and longer.

I know about the following three facts: Eclipse needs a lot of HD access, and Samba can't cope with many small files to be sent to a network share, and it isn't a problem with our infrastructure - we have GiB-ethernet and everything usually works extremely fast.

Has anyone of you ever worked in such a setting (project with many small files located on a network share)? And, has anyone of you a good idea to speed up Eclipse/the project build in such a setting?

I highly appreciate any hint or tipp! Thank you a lot in advance!

Benjamin

Comment: Why not use local files with version control of your choice?

Comment: Hello dutt, the reason to use a network share is as follows: our students here at university have to solve programming exercises in the lab. They have their accounts and should use their projects whereever they want (any other lab) and I have no possibility to set up a CVS/SVN/whatever for them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Where are your workspaces, local or on the network?

Where do you build your files, local or on the network?

Both of these should be done locally and will make for a significant improvement in speed. That a full refresh takes time with alot of files over a network, well, that might be reasonable. To know for sure, you need to determine what is causing the slowdown.

Do a timed filecopy from share to local or something similar with a large Eclipse project, take the time it takes per file. Then do a full refresh of the same project in Eclipse and compare the times.

Networks can be set up differently and handle either large files quickly, or lot of small files quickly. We have issues with this, especially in windows since there are some checks with regards to access rights that takes time.

Comment: Hi Frederik, thank you for your reply! Both, workspaces and build process are/take place on the network. We already did a copy-and-refresh comparison, with no significant difference. We played around with our Samba-configuration, but with no effect. So, my question was about "other tipps". :-) You wrote, that you also have somehow similar issues. Do you have any further tipps for me? Thank you a lot, Benjamin

Comment: Step 1: Do all build and have workspace on your local drive. If you need to share build artifacts, copy them after the build. 
Secondly, if the comparison showed little difference then the fault is in the network. It's beyond my skills unfortunately, but I know the network can be setup to better handle many small files, rather than few large files. Discuss this with your network admin. Try asking a question on www.serverfault.com, they might know more.